# Display Some Nodes with their weights

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, graph

I have a some nodes(points) count between 1 to 20 and this nodes have weights to connect with each other(Distance in Salesman problem). How I can show them with proportionate weights In Windows Application?

thanks

**Edit 1)**
Graphs I want to show are similar this graphs:

[image]
[image]

Comment: first you said you want to show them in windows application and then you asked you want to show them in ASP.Net !!!!!!

Comment: I mean if there is a way to show them in ASP.Net show to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exactly this problem, I created a Graph/Node/Connection class in C#.

Using this example:
 [image]

It shows you all info about the route. For example from B to C:

```
Node B  length connection 0     total lenght 0
Node D  length connection 6     total lenght 6
Node F  length connection 4     total lenght 10
Node C  length connection 8     total lenght 18
```

More examples and full source code in this post:
[Create your own navigation system (with a Graph, Node and Connection class)](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2014/03/02/Graph-Node-and-Connection-Create-your-own-navigation-system.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising: [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/demos.html)
Specifically: [this Demo](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/ForceDirected/example1.html)

Or [Raphaël—JavaScript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/) with [this demo](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html).